# Single Confluent Kafka cluster in different host machine

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I want to mount a Confluent Kafka Cluster in Kraft mode, in which, each broker is containerized in a Docker container. Each of this broker should be placed on different host machine. I want that two of there are both controller and broker, and one of them only broker. To be more clear:

1. broker_1 ---> HOST_MACHINE_1 with IP IP_1 [controller,broker]
2. broker_2 ---> HOST_MACHINE_2 with IP IP_2 [broker]
3. broker_3 ---> HOST_MACHINE_3 with IP IP_3 [controller,broker]

As first trial I started to write the docker-compose file of the first broker, but I have doubt on how setup the inter-broker communication.

```
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  kafka-data:
    driver: local

services:
  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka1
    container_name: broker
    volumes:
      - kafka-data:/var/lib/kafka/data:Z
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "false"
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,KAFKA1:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'KAFKA1://kafka1:29092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@kafka1:29093,3@IP_3:29093'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'KAFKA1://kafka1:29092,CONTROLLER://broker:29093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'KAFKA1'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
      CLUSTER_ID: 'testId'
```

Should I have to add the HOST:PORT mapping on the KAFKA_LISTENERS (ie. KAFKA2://IP_2:9092,KAFKA3://IP_3:9092)?
Should I declare the same CLUSTER_ID on the other two Compose files?

I am a little bit lost, I would be very thankful if someone explain me better the dynamics of these operation in a general way, so, not specifically bound to this use case. I put it to facilitate the explanation.

Comment: Maybe this article help you https://levelup.gitconnected.com/kraft-kafka-cluster-with-docker-e79a97d19f2c

Comment: First of all thanks for the comment. I had already achieved how to launch the cluster on a single machine. But I need to have each broker on different machine. And still I don't understand how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if run containers on different hosts each host must resolve neighbour names, network traffic between hosts must be allowed on used ports(9091,9092 and etc), no more localhost in config), in config will use real host names and ports or ip addresses.
Example configs for 3 hosts. First host name is host1, second is host2 ... host3

Config for host1:

```
version: '3'
services:
  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    container_name: kafka1
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29093:29093"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://host1:29092,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:29093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INTERNAL'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@host1:29093,2@host2:29093,3@host3:29093'
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CLUSTER_ID: 'ciWo7IWazngRchmPES6q5A=='
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
```

Config for host2:

```
version: '3'
services:
  kafka2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    container_name: kafka2
    hostname: kafka2
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29093:29093"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 2
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://host2:29092,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:29093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INTERNAL'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@host1:29093,2@host2:29093,3@host3:29093'
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CLUSTER_ID: 'ciWo7IWazngRchmPES6q5A=='
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
```

Config for host3:

```
  kafka3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    container_name: kafka3
    hostname: kafka3
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29093:29093"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 3
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: 'CONTROLLER'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: 'CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT'
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://host3:29092,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:29093,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:29092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092'
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: 'INTERNAL'
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@host1:29093,2@host2:29093,3@host3:29093'
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'broker,controller'
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3
      CLUSTER_ID: 'ciWo7IWazngRchmPES6q5A=='
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    hostname: schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'host1:29092,host2:29092,host3:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: 'http://0.0.0.0:8081'
    depends_on:
      - kafka3

networks:
  default:
    name: my-network
    external: true
```

Configs can be had mistakes) But idea is this. I hope it help.

Comment: Thanks, now it seems working.Only a couple of point to correct this answer. In KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS you cannot put the address 0.0.0.0, and in KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS in each host you have to put not the host address but the hostname declared in the compose file, because putting host address seems doesn't work, at least for me